# Python matrix using min function in k-means

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to learn k-means from Book"Machine Learning in Action" now.
Using the code given by this book in ipython notebook, the outcome

```
matrix([[<map object at 0x0000000008832C88>]], dtype=object)
```

happened after I input `locMat = mat(loadDataSet("user1.txt"))` and `min(locMat[:,0])`.

What the meaning of that outcome? Why is not a exact value like 3.245555? The code is showed below, thank you in advanced!

```
def loadDataSet(fileName):     
    dataMat = []             
    fr = open(fileName)
    for line in fr.readlines():
    curLine = line.strip().split('\t')
    fltLine = map(float,curLine) #map all elements to float()
    dataMat.append(fltLine)
    return dataMat

def distEclud(vecA, vecB):
    return sqrt(sum(power(vecA - vecB, 2))) #la.norm(vecA-vecB)

def randCent(dataSet, k):
    n = shape(dataSet)[1]
    centroids = mat(zeros((k,n)))
    for j in range(n):
        minJ = min(dataSet[:,j]) 
        rangeJ = float(max(dataSet[:,j]) - minJ)
        centroids[:,j] = mat(minJ + rangeJ * random.rand(k,1))
    return centroids
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using Python 3, where `map` returns a generator instead of a list.

You need to use `fltLine = list(map(float, curLine))` or `fltLine = [float(x) for x in curLine]` to make sure that the result is a list, then things will work as expected.

Since I assume you're using numpy here, you can use the `genfromtxt` function to load your data file:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt(fileName)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! There are many differents between Python 3 and 2. Thanks a lot!